# How to find records that match in collection using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

In the sample data below I need to find how many TransitMapSegmentIDs match TransitLine's 10803 TransitMapSegmentIDs, which would be 2 since 101 and 102 match.

I've been looking at this for a few hours and I'm a little cross eyed and would appreciate some help.  Thanks!

```
public class TransitLineSegment
{
    public int TransitLineID { get; set; }
    public string TransitLineName { get; set; }
    public int TransitMapSegmentID { get; set; }
    public string HexColor { get; set; }
    public double[][] Coordinates { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
}
```

sample data

```
TransitMapSegmentID  TransitLineID
101                  10803
102                  10803
64                   10807
67                   10807
101                          10807
102                          10807
```

Comment: The wording of your question is misleading.  You might want to consider rewording.  Specifically your example explanation says you want to find two matching TransitMapSegmentIDs for a TransitLineId=10803 which would be TransitMapSegmentIDs=101 & TransitMapSegmentIDs=102.   Note that 101 & 102 do not match, hence that statement makes 0 sense.  Also your example (num segments per line) goes exactly opposite to what you explain in your first paragraph (num lines per segment).

Answer (score 2):

You could combine a `Where` filter and `GroupBy`:

```
var result = transitLineSegments
            .Where(ls => ls.TransitLineID == 10803)
            .GroupBy(ls => ls.TransitMapSegmentID)
            .Select(grp => grp.Count());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [GroupBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby.aspx) method. You should be able to group by TransitLineID and get the list for each id, where you can get the first or count them.

```
var uni = from segment in segments
      group segment by segment.TransitLineID into segmentGroup
      select new { Id = segmentGroup.Key, Count = segmentGroup.Count() };

foreach(var seg in uni)
    Console.WriteLine ("Id: {0}, Count: {1}", seg.Id, seg.Count);
```

Comment: How would I do a GroupBy with a condition, because I need to filter out the ones that are under the same id.